# "abc" w/3 "def" w/5 "ghi" (exact proximity search using Lucene)

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I need to be able to full text search for "abc" w/3 "def" w/5 "ghi" using Lucene.  I realize that I could use a proximity search like this to approximate that: "abc def ghi"~8.  However, I need the exact precision of within 3 for the first two terms and within 5 for the second two terms.  The only way I can think of doing this is to search for:
"abc def ghi"~8 && "abc def"~3 && "def ghi"~5.  Does anyone have any other ideas, perhaps more efficient, on how to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

"abc def ghi"~8 && "abc def"~3 && "def ghi"~5 is different than “abc” w/3 “def” w/5 “ghi” Here is why

I assume you want to find a document that has the terms below:

abc,1,2,3,def,1,2,3,4,5,ghi

Both queries will find the document above. But the first query will also find this

abc 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,def,1,2,3,4,5,6,8 ghi , a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,abc,1,2,3,def,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,def,1,2,3,4,5,ghi

I think you don't want the second document in your search results.

I don't know much about the .NET version of Lucene. it seems like it supports span queries. You can use span queries for proximity searches.

```
    SpanNearQuery spanNear = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
      new SpanTermQuery(new Term(FIELD, "abc")),
      new SpanTermQuery(new Term(FIELD, "def"))},
      3,
      true);

    Query queryToBeExecuted = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {
      spanNear,
      new SpanTermQuery(new Term(FIELD, "ghi"))},
      5,
      true);
```

You can use queryToBeExecuted query for your search.

For mor info check Mark Miller's article about [span queries](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/).

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same problem. Lucene's query language is not very robust.  In addition to being unable to string together proximity searches, it is also difficult to perform boolean operations and phrase queries within a proximity query.

I solved the problem by writing my own query parser and manually instantiating query primitives.  Writing your own query parser is not easy, but it gives you a lot of flexibility. In my new query language, I use w/N to specify a proximity query.  With it, the following complex queries become possible:

```
foo w/3 bar w/5 biz
foo w/3 bar w/5 (biz or buz)
```

Or even more complex queries

```
("first part" within/3 foo) w/10 ("second part" within/3 (bar or biz))
```

I wrote the query parser in python using `pyparsing`. It's a project, but it's a fun project and you end up with something much more powerful than the lucene query parser.